# UI5 - How should be the routing part to Navigate from the same view to a master-detail page and also to another view?

Tags: sapui5

I want to navigate from  view 'A' to a splitscreen and also from view 'A' to a normal View.

First part is working fine but having problem with the second part.I am getting the following error.

> GET fooPath/sap/opu/odata/SAP/ZEMPLOYEE_APP_SRV/analytics 404 (Not Found)

I have the following routing config in my component.js:

```
routing : {
        config : {
            routerClass : sap.app.frm.MyRouter,
            viewType : "XML",
            viewPath : "sap.app.frm.view",
            targetAggregation  : "pages",
            clearTarget : false,
            transition : "slide"
        },
        routes : [ {
            pattern: "",
            name: "Home",
            view: "Home",
            targetAggregation: "pages",
            targetControl: "masterApp"
        },
        {
        pattern : "employeeRecords",
        name : "main",
        view : "SplitContainer",
        targetAggregation : "pages",
        targetControl : "masterApp",
        subroutes : [ {
            pattern : "subro1",
            name : "master",
            view : "Master",
            targetAggregation : "masterPages",
            targetControl : "idAppControl",
            subroutes : [{
                pattern: "{Zempid}",
                name: "detail",
                view: "Detail",
                targetAggregation: "detailPages"
            }]
        } ]
    },
    {
        name : "catchallMaster",
        view : "Master",
        targetAggregation : "masterPages",
        targetControl : "idSplitContainerControl",
        subroutes : [ {
            pattern : ":all*:",
            name : "catchallDetail",
            view : "NotFound",
            transition : "flip"
        } ]
    },{
        pattern: "analytics",
        name: "analytics",
        view: "analytics.AnalyticsHome",

   }]
}
```

Hoping somebody can help me out.

Thank you

Febin

Comment: Your error doesn't sound like it is an issue with the routing, but rather your OData service.

Comment: @hirse okie. In that case how the url is changing to that of the oData. I haven't specified anything related in the patterns right? Any idea on that? I will share any other part of code if needed. Thanks for your response.